# can't drag clip to timeline in Kdenlive in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drag-and-drop, kdenlive

Recently, I upgraded Ubuntu to 23.04. I am using Kdenlive, but I cannot drag clips from the project bin to the timeline. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: same here, the V trick found here in the answer section helped me but it's kindof crazy that this hasn't been fixed yet. it's good to note that this happens for the flatpak and deb versions of kdenlive

Comment: Here's the bug report for it: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2715 X11 vs Wayland appears to affect the issue according to: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2715#note_1753579 it worked on Wayland for that user. Found on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/kdenlive/comments/12x0t6s/kdenlive_drag_and_drop_not_working/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup! This threw me too when I first tried Kdenlive on 23.04. Here's how you do it.

- Highlight clip at the top
- Press the V key

That'll insert the highlighted clip into the timeline.

Comment: Im having the same issue and this is frustrating... I found out about using the V key to atleast work around the issue BUT working this way AUTOMATICALLY cuts all the clips already in the timeline to make space for the new clip.. this can be a headache when dealing with numerous clips at a time and having to constantly go to an empty spot in the whole project just to add a clip in to avoid having to fix all the clips that will be cut/split when adding a new clip ... I hope someone can find a fix to the simpler drag and drop soon

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. My workaround is to drag video files directly from the file manager into the Kdenlive timeline. They appear in the bin after this action, too. From there it is currently impossible to drag them into the timeline.
(Ubuntu 23.04, Kdenlive 22.12.3)

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop also does not work when inserting effects or transitions. This is the workaround:

Transitions:

choose the transition
right click -> add to favourites
mark the desired clip in the timeline
right mouse button -> add a transition

Effects:

Mark the clip
choose the desired effect
double click

B

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have the same issue and i resolved the import videos to timeline. I drag and drop with a file from my files, no from program kdenlive.
all of this is in a linux debian system.

Answer (score 0):

**I found an easy solution (I’m using ubuntu 23.04):**

The root of the problem was mutter: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2715

Go to: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter
And download the mutter 44.2 version, which includes the fix.

These are the packages needed for 64bit:

```
gir1.2-mutter-12_44.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libmutter-12-0_44.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
mutter-common_44.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
mutter-common-bin_44.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Then open up a terminal and install them with:

```
sudo dpkg --install gir1.2-mutter-12_44.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libmutter-12-0_44.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
mutter-common_44.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
mutter-common-bin_44.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Logout / Restart system. You can now edit as normal again.
This also solved not being able to drop effects unto the tracks.